# Is it possible to add a key binding to an OpenGL display window?

Tags: java, swing, opengl

So I want to add a key binding that will close the window when escape is pressed. However, the program has to use a Display window rather than JFrames and/or JPanels, as in created like this:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
public void createWindow() throws Exception {
    Display.setFullscreen(false);
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
    Display.create();
}
```

This is because it is for an assignment that requires us to use glVertex2f(x, y) to draw points. As far as I am aware, in order to use glVertex2f(x, y) you cannot be using JPanels, though if there is a way to do that, that would also solve the problem. 
My question is, is there any way to add a keybinding to a display?

Edit: thanks Vince's suggestion was what I needed. Fortunately quite simple.

Comment: I don't recall there being a `Display` type for Swing. Can't find the javadocs online for it. Where is the `Display` type coming from?

Comment: It's part of opengl

Comment: Why don't you [listen for key events](http://ninjacave.com/lwjglbasics2), then call `destroy` if the key way pressed? Doesn't seem as this question is related to Swing

Comment: The program uses both opengl and swing, though from your comment I now understand that opengl has it's own version of key bindings. That solved the issue, so thanks! Sorry if this was an obvious question but I'm new to both opengl and swing.

Comment: I though lwjgl had it's own input mechanisms